# Calculating the area of the irregular darker circle in the image below using python

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, annotations

[image]

I wanted to use this particular image and calculate the area of the darker region which is irregular shaped. I have many such images in different folders (each folder having each image). This way if I iterate the process in a for loop I should be able to get a table outlining area of the each image in one go. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service, it is for answering specific and focused questions. What have you tried so far and what doesn't work about it? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can binarize your image and then sum the pixels for an approximated area, in terms of pixels. For realistic approximation, you should convert from pixels to your dimension according to your resolution.

For your image, I got the following:

```
impot cv2
img = cv2.imread('67EAS.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

[image: original image in grayscale]

Binarizing with Otsu, you can try other algorithms:

```
thresh, bin_img = cv2.threshold(img, img.min(), img.max(), cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

[image: Binarized image, the darker area has 0 values]

Convert black to white pixels (we want to sum the darker pixels to find de desired area).

```
bin_img= cv2.bitwise_not(bin_img)
```

[image: Binarized image, the darker area has 1 values]

Now, set the max value from 255 to 1, and then sum all pixels.

```
bin_img = bin_img/255
bin_img.sum()
```

As a result, we got:

```
186185.0
```

That means, for your image (shape = (649, 812)), we have 186185 out of 526988 pixels (~35.3%) in the 'darker area' by the Otsu strategy.

Of course, it's an approximation. For a more precise evaluation, you can find the best circle with `cv2.HoughCircles` and only consider the pixels inside it.